# Copy range with conditional formatting

Tags: copy, conditional-formatting, epplus

I have a range with Conditional Formatting in an existing Excel file. I used EPPlus to copy that range to a new sheet, then I found the conditional formatting was missing.

Is there any way to copy range with conditional formatting using EPPlus?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for this.  I did not test it on all formattingRuleTypes.  (Only needed 2 of them for the moment)
In my application i have 1 template row for each sheet.

```
     var formatList = fromSheet.ConditionalFormatting.ToList();
        foreach (var cf in formatList)
        {
            // sourceRow is the row containing the formatting
            if (cf.Address.Start.Row == sourceRow )
            {
                IExcelConditionalFormattingRule rule = null;
                switch (cf.Type)
                {                      
                    case OfficeOpenXml.ConditionalFormatting.eExcelConditionalFormattingRuleType.GreaterThan:
                        rule = dest.ConditionalFormatting.AddGreaterThan();                            
                        break;
                    case OfficeOpenXml.ConditionalFormatting.eExcelConditionalFormattingRuleType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                        rule = dest.ConditionalFormatting.AddGreaterThanOrEqual();
                        break;
                    case OfficeOpenXml.ConditionalFormatting.eExcelConditionalFormattingRuleType.LessThan:
                        rule = dest.ConditionalFormatting.AddLessThan();
                        break;
                    case OfficeOpenXml.ConditionalFormatting.eExcelConditionalFormattingRuleType.LessThanOrEqual:
                        rule = dest.ConditionalFormatting.AddLessThanOrEqual();
                        break;                     
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                rule.Style.Fill = cf.Style.Fill;
                rule.Style.Border = cf.Style.Border;
                rule.Style.Font = cf.Style.Font;
                rule.Style.NumberFormat = cf.Style.NumberFormat;

                // I have no clue why the Formula property is not included in the     IExcelConditionalFormattingRule interface.  So I needed to cast this.
                ((ExcelConditionalFormattingRule)rule).Formula = ((ExcelConditionalFormattingRule)cf).Formula;
                ((ExcelConditionalFormattingRule)rule).Formula2 = ((ExcelConditionalFormattingRule)cf).Formula2;


                // Calculate the new address for the formatting.   This will be different in your case    
                var adr = new ExcelAddress( dest.Start.Row , cf.Address.Start.Column -1 , dest.Start.Row, cf.Address.Start.Column -1 + cf.Address.Columns -1 );


                rule.Address = adr;
```

I have no clue why the Formula property is not included in the IExcelConditionalFormattingRule interface.  So I needed to cast this.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of Luc Wuyts (I can't comment yet due to limited reputation):

```html
                // I have no clue why the Formula property is not included in the     IExcelConditionalFormattingRule interface.  So I needed to cast this.
                ((ExcelConditionalFormattingRule)rule).Formula = ((ExcelConditionalFormattingRule)cf).Formula;
                ((ExcelConditionalFormattingRule)rule).Formula2 = ((ExcelConditionalFormattingRule)cf).Formula2;
```

Some conditional formatting do not have the Formula-options. This cast will work, but applying the Formula properties to conditional formatting options which do not require it will have unforeseen results. Eg. the ConditionalFormatting.AddContainsBlanks() does not require Formula properties, and adding them might mess up the conditional formatting. A better approach is to check the type, and add the formula's only when required.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, the only way I found to inspect, change or delete a conditional format of a cell or range is looking at the openxml specs.  The conditional format is stored in the worksheet, with the range under the attribute sqref.  So you can edit that range or add a new.

For example:

```
DIM p As New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(ExlReportPath), True)
Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets(ExlSheetName)
```

'--Find Node "worksheet" (1 in my case) , Find all Child Nodes "conditionalFormatting" (5 to 11 in my test)

```
Print.Debug(ws.WorksheetXml.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(5).Name)
```

'--You get: conditionalFormatting

'--Now you can inspect the range:

```
Print.Debug(ws.WorksheetXml.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(5).Attributes("sqref").Value)
```

'--Will give you the cell address that this formatting applies to example: "D11:D15"
'--you can change delete or add new range if you want, below I add F11:F15

```
ws.WorksheetXml.ChildNodes(1).ChildNodes(5).Attributes("sqref").Value="D11:D15 F11:F15"
```

'--You can inspect the rule itself in the InnerXml also...

If you need more details of the markup, google  Wouter van Vugt, "Open XML The markup explained".  I found it useful and the full document was online (free).

If you find an easier way please post it.

Regards